# Sailsjs - creating models dynamically

Tags: sails.js

In sails js can models be created dynamically from controller?

At bootstrap there are few basic models listed in app, then dynamically need to add models

Are there any possible ways to do it ?

Comment: are you asking about a  way to generate models like controllers can be generated using sails generate controllers controller_name ?

Comment: no, I want to create models on user request. So i cant have any predefined models under model folder.